# Unable to import undirected graph from EdgeList file in igraph-python

Tags: python, graph, igraph, network-analysis

I am using the igraph-python's `Graph.Read_Ncol` function. Below is my code for reading the data.

```
def loadData(filename):
    data = None
    data = ig.Graph.Read_Ncol(filename, directed=False)
    return data
```

I am using this dataset from SNAP group: https://snap.stanford.edu/data/ca-GrQc.html
As mentioned the dataset has 14496 edges and 5242 nodes.

However when I do `data.summary()` on my graph I get the following output.

```
>>> data.summary()
'IGRAPH UN-- 5242 28980 -- \n+ attr: name (v)'
```

Even when I am doing `data.to_undirected()` and trying `data.summary()` again I am getting the same result as above.

```
>>> data.to_undirected()
>>> data.summary()
'IGRAPH UN-- 5242 28980 -- \n+ attr: name (v)'
```

When I am loading the graph using the SNAP library in an undirected fashion then I am getting the correct output.

```
def loadData(filename):
    data = None
    data = snap.LoadEdgeList(snap.PUNGraph,filename,0,1)

    return data
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is there an issue with the igraph API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the edges appear twice in your network, and igraphs adds them as multiple edges. Call `simplify()` on the graph to remove these multiple edges. http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#simplify